# Installed Python 3.5.2 (64bit) however can't open python

Tags: python

I have installed Python 3.5.2 (64bit) however once I had installed it I couldn't find a link to open python and I couldn't find it on the program files. Is there a way to open it on the run command or how do I open it?

I am using a 64bit AMD processsor and Windows 7 home basic 64 bit

Kind Regards

Comment: Have you tried typing python into CMD

Comment: IDLE *should* be installed

Comment: And the default python folder on windows seems to install in `C:\python`, not Program Files

Comment: Give us some more details on what system you are using. Also, go to https://www.python.org/ to see how to use.

Comment: @cricket_007 I can't find it on C:\python

Comment: @UnknownDeveloper I have tried typing python into cmd and it says python is recogised as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Comment: I would recommend running the installer again and make sure you check to install both IDLE and let the installer change the PATH

Answer (score 0):

**Windows**

Default location on Windows `C:\Python` 
You can open cmd type `python` SHELL opens immediatly 
If python command not recognized you can add python location: `C:\Python` to `PATH` Environment variable 
Then reopen cmd type `python`
Also you can find `IDLE` in start menu

Comment: It says python is recogised as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Comment: Sorry try to search for IDLE in startmenu

Comment: @S.Laura if you cannot find IDLE Check this link for installation guide http://www.howtogeek.com/197947/how-to-install-python-on-windows/amp/